# Warm-start fitting example notebook of Prophet crashes

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am using the exact same code as cell #5 in this [example](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/main/notebooks/additional_topics.ipynb), found from this Github [issue](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1565):

```
from prophet import Prophet
def warm_start_params(m):
    """
    Retrieve parameters from a trained model in the format used to initialize a new Stan model.
    Note that the new Stan model must have these same settings:
        n_changepoints, seasonality features, mcmc sampling
    for the retrieved parameters to be valid for the new model.

    Parameters
    ----------
    m: A trained model of the Prophet class.

    Returns
    -------
    A Dictionary containing retrieved parameters of m.
    """
    res = {}
    for pname in ['k', 'm', 'sigma_obs']:
        if m.mcmc_samples == 0:
            res[pname] = m.params[pname][0][0]
        else:
            res[pname] = np.mean(m.params[pname])
    for pname in ['delta', 'beta']:
        if m.mcmc_samples == 0:
            res[pname] = m.params[pname][0]
        else:
            res[pname] = np.mean(m.params[pname], axis=0)
    return res

df = pd.read_csv('example_wp_log_peyton_manning.csv')
df1 = df.loc[df['ds'] < '2016-01-19', :]  # All data except the last day
m1 = Prophet().fit(df1) # A model fit to all data except the last day


%timeit m2 = Prophet().fit(df)  # Adding the last day, fitting from scratch
%timeit m2 = Prophet().fit(df, init=warm_start_params(m1))  # Adding the last day, warm-starting from m1
```

But it crashes on warm-start, output:

```
11:40:57 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:40:58 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
11:40:58 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:40:59 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
11:40:59 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:41:00 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
11:41:00 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:41:01 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
11:41:01 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:41:02 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
11:41:02 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:41:03 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
11:41:03 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:41:04 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
11:41:04 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:41:05 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
11:41:05 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
11:41:06 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
1.09 s ± 85.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 36
     32 m1 = Prophet().fit(df1) # A model fit to all data except the last day
     35 get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'm2 = Prophet().fit(df)  # Adding the last day, fitting from scratch')
---> 36 get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'm2 = Prophet().fit(df, init=warm_start_params(m1))  # Adding the last day, warm-starting from m1')

File /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2369, in InteractiveShell.run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2367     kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2368 with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2369     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2371 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2372 # when using magics with decodator @output_can_be_silenced
   2373 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2374 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py:1163, in ExecutionMagics.timeit(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1161 for index in range(0, 10):
   1162     number = 10 ** index
-> 1163     time_number = timer.timeit(number)
   1164     if time_number >= 0.2:
   1165         break

File /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py:157, in Timer.timeit(self, number)
    155 gc.disable()
    156 try:
--> 157     timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
    158 finally:
    159     if gcold:

File <magic-timeit>:1, in inner(_it, _timer)

File /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prophet/forecaster.py:1174, in Prophet.fit(self, df, **kwargs)
   1172     self.params = self.stan_backend.sampling(stan_init, dat, self.mcmc_samples, **kwargs)
   1173 else:
-> 1174     self.params = self.stan_backend.fit(stan_init, dat, **kwargs)
   1176 self.stan_fit = self.stan_backend.stan_fit
   1177 # If no changepoints were requested, replace delta with 0s

File /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prophet/models.py:85, in CmdStanPyBackend.fit(self, stan_init, stan_data, **kwargs)
     82 (stan_init, stan_data) = self.prepare_data(stan_init, stan_data)
     84 if 'inits' not in kwargs and 'init' in kwargs:
---> 85     kwargs['inits'] = self.prepare_data(kwargs['init'], stan_data)[0]
     87 args = dict(
     88     data=stan_data,
     89     inits=stan_init,
     90     algorithm='Newton' if stan_data['T'] < 100 else 'LBFGS',
     91     iter=int(1e4),
     92 )
     93 args.update(kwargs)

File /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prophet/models.py:154, in CmdStanPyBackend.prepare_data(init, data)
    146 @staticmethod
    147 def prepare_data(init, data) -> Tuple[dict, dict]:
    148     cmdstanpy_data = {
    149         'T': data['T'],
    150         'S': data['S'],
    151         'K': data['K'],
    152         'tau': data['tau'],
    153         'trend_indicator': data['trend_indicator'],
--> 154         'y': data['y'].tolist(),
    155         't': data['t'].tolist(),
    156         'cap': data['cap'].tolist(),
    157         't_change': data['t_change'].tolist(),
    158         's_a': data['s_a'].tolist(),
    159         's_m': data['s_m'].tolist(),
    160         'X': data['X'].to_numpy().tolist(),
    161         'sigmas': data['sigmas']
    162     }
    164     cmdstanpy_init = {
    165         'k': init['k'],
    166         'm': init['m'],
   (...)
    169         'sigma_obs': init['sigma_obs']
    170     }
    171     return (cmdstanpy_init, cmdstanpy_data)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

My Prophet version is 1.1.1 (which I can't upgrade now in my project due to this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/2354)).